# When should I use Solandra

Tags: cassandra, solandra

I am planning to use Cassandra to store my users passwords and at the same time the data for my website that need to be accessible via search. My Question is should I use two DB: Cassandra (for users passwords) and Solandra (for the websites data) or can I put everything in Solandra?

Is there a way to stop Solandra from indexing my users passwords?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hope you have a good reason to store passwords instead of their hashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solandra does not index the data you have in cassandra, it only uses its own keyspace to store data you index through solr.  So I think you should keep the two separate.